# How to get a C# string type from an int8 pointer using DllImport

Tags: c#, c++, c, dllimport

I would like to use a DLL function that was written in C but I don't know how to write the **DllImport** function to retrieve a string in C#.  The C function signature looks like this:

```
void ni845xStatusToString (int32 StatusCode, uInt32 MaxSize, int8 * pStatusString);
```

I would like to get the string that **pStatusString** is pointing to.  My C# code looks like this:

```
[DllImport("Ni845x.dll")]
public static extern void ni845xStatusToString(int StatusCode, int MaxSizeOfStatusStr, ref IntPtr StatusStrPtr);
```

Then inside my function I use it like this:

```
IntPtr statusStrPtr = IntPtr.Zero; // = new StringBuilder(1048);
ni845xStatusToString(error, 1048, ref statusStrPtr);

string statusStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(statusStrPtr);   // <-- HERE returns empty string and statusStrPtr is not zero.  

MessageBox.Show("Error description: " + statusStr);
```

I don't get any errors using this approach but **statusStr** is always empty.

Thank you.

Comment: Check your calling conventions on both sides and make sure they match up.

Comment: why not try something like this and then convert it to a string after or use .ToString() at the end of (statusStrPrt); part of the code..?
`uint statusStrAsInt = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(statusStrPtr);` not sure if this link will help or not http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx

Comment: Thanks @DJKRAZE. I get this error when I execute this 'uint statusStrAsInt = (uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(statusStrPtr)'  The error is as follows: FatalExecutionEngineError was detected
Message: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x680afd8c, on thread 0x214c. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Comment: can you show your using at the top of the .cs file..? do you have this `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Comment: Yes I do have that `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` why?

Comment: for that error look at `(uint)` try changing it to `uInt32`

Comment: Your original attempt with StringBuilder was correct.  What you came up with next was not, this function requires passing a buffer.  Classic problem btw, SO users posting their last and least likely to be correct attempt at making it work.  Don't do that.  Contact National Instruments if you need support.

Comment: What happens when you do: `GCHandle memalloc = GCHandle.Alloc(1024, GCHandleType.Pinned); 
IntPtr statusStrPtr = memalloc.AddrOfPinnedObject();` Any of those bytes get changed? might need to ditch the ref... bit of a long-shot

Comment: @HansPassant, The `StringBuilder` worked.  I had to drop the `ref` part duh.  Thank you.